# Files doen't gets created in Android sdcard

Tags: android, file, android-sdcard

Im trying to create a file(TranReport.pdf) within a folder TransactionReport(user selectedDate) but i'm facing some issue.Can you please advice where i'm doing wrong.

Code

```
            try {

            File pdfFolder = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                            + "Android/AMSP/", "TransactionReport(" + date
                            + ")");
            if (!pdfFolder.exists()) {
                pdfFolder.mkdir();
                Log.i("", "Pdf Directory created");
            }

            File myFile = new File(pdfFolder, "TranReport" + ".pdf");

            writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(
                    myFile));
```

Comment: Can you describe which issue you faced

Comment: In which device and os version you used to run this app ?

Comment: In a Genemotion Emulator 4.4.4 I'm trying to run it and the folder itself not getting created.@YogeshRathi

Comment: Have u added write external storage permission

Comment: Yes I have added it

Comment: Can you paste exact which error you faced

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/AMSP/TransactionReport(12/1/2015)/TranReport.pdf: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: getExternalStoragePublicDirectory use this method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120827/discussion-between-pranesh-sahu-and-yogesh-rathi).

Answer (score 0):

The issue got resolved by changing pdfFolder.mkdir(); to pdfFolder.mkdirs();